# how to fix AttributeError: module 'scipy.linalg' has no attribute 'inv'

Tags: python, scipy, attributeerror

ipython

```
import deeplabcut 

AttributeError: module 'scipy.linalg' has no attribute 'inv'
```

When I import deeplabcut at ipython, attribute error occured.

I try

`pip3 install scipy-stack` at anaconda prompt,

`import scipy.linalg.inv` at ipython,

and `from scipy import inv` at ipython.

but I can't fix this error.

Comment: I think you to have install it like: pip3/conda install scipy. Here's are the instructions: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/getting_started.html. Also here is the documentation for inv() https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.inv.html

Comment: it is `from scipy import linalg` not `import scipy.linalg.inv`

Comment: thank you very much!
I can fix this error by "conda install scipy"